# Custom time periods in DAX

Tags: time, powerbi, dax, period

I have a huge table where entries have product categories, create date, modify date, etc. Marketing in our company is launching campaigns in several "Promotional Periods" which are gathered in table with: Product category, Promotion name, start date, end date

I need to find a way to filter sales by promotional period. Can You please advice should I add some column in query editor, or rather calculated column with DAX which would add the Promotion name based on product category and creation date in range between start and end. Example code would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your promotional periods can overlap. 
Here an example with a period table:

datamodel:

[image: Datamodel]

Measure: 
We filter the date table, only on the records between the period start and end dates.

```
Total Amount Period:=Calculate(
[Total Amount],
    FILTER('Date',
            COUNTROWS(FILTER('Period',
                    Period[PeriodStart] <='Date'[DateValue] &&
                    Period[PeriodEnd] >= 'Date'[DateValue] ))
            > 0)
    )
```

The solution file (excel 2016): 
[ExcelFile](http://wimv.be/forumpost/stackoverflow_customPeriod.xlsx)

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
Unfortunately I need a little bit different solution:
first I need to qualify each entry in table A to one and only one Promotional periods from table B. 
Promotional period is described by type of product it applies to AND if it's a returning customer (boolean) AND after I have those set - I'll have just the promotional periods for this customer filtered out where I can search for proper period by finding in which period (between start and end dates) does the date of sale fits. Probably I should add column with name of this period to table A for filtering purposes.